# How can I strip text from XML elements, rearrange it, and concatenate it with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-1.0

Considering the following XML:

```
<root>
  <contrib contrib-type="author">
    <name>
      <last-name>Simpson</last-name>
      <first-name>Bart</first-name>
    </name>
  </contrib>

  <contrib contrib-type="author">
    <name>
      <last-name>Zoidberg</last-name>
      <first-name>Dr.</first-name>
    </name>
  </contrib>
</root>
```

...how can I transform the contents of these elements to get this output?

```
<Authors contrib-type="author">Bart Simpson</Authors>
<Authors contrib-type="author">Dr. Zoidberg</Authors>
```

---

I am trying to concatenate the contents of  `<first-name>`  with the contents of  `<last-name>` , and **separated by a single space**.

Also, there is no need for any sub-elements of  `Authors` (getting rid of the  `<name>` ,  `<first-name>` , and  `<last-name>`  elements if possible).

---

This is the XSL I have so far (*which is not working*):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <!-- Authors -->
        <xsl:template match="contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
            <Authors>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select = "concat(given-names, surname)" />
            </Authors>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So far, I am able to transform the  `<contrib>`  element to  `<Authors>` , but am not able to concatenate or strip its' sub-elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <!-- Authors -->
        <xsl:template match="contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
            <Authors contrib-type="{@contrib-type}">
                <xsl:value-of select = "concat(name/first-name, ' ', name/last-name)" />
            </Authors>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope this would help

Comment: you are welcome, if you have question do let me know I am more then happy to answer as much as simpler and as sophisticated as I can. :)

Answer (score 2):

try something as simple as this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/contrib"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Authors -->
<xsl:template match="contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
    <Authors>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="name/first-name"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name/last-name"/>
    </Authors>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ah, this is interesting using `<xsl:text>`, was not aware of that, thanks @mabroukb.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing the point, changing your Authors template to the following should work:

```
<!-- Authors -->
<xsl:template match="contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
    <Authors>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select = "concat(normalize-space(name/first-name/text()), 
                                       ' ', 
                                       normalize-space(name/last-name/text()))" />
    </Authors>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <Authors contrib-type="author">Bart Simpson</Authors>
  <Authors contrib-type="author">Dr. Zoidberg</Authors>
</root>
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks @nonnb for the help. What exactly is `normalize-space` doing in this context?

Comment: Ah I see -- it is removing leading and trailing whitespaces from the `text()`. This is interesting, didn't know you could access the "inner XML" with `text()`.